# Dynamic price for a product

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, price, dynamic-price

I have product named "Basic Plan" and "Premium Plan", which have a fixed but different price.

However, I would like to add one more, which allows customer to UPGRADE to Premium Plan, when he has purchased Basic Plan already.

The price will be dynamic, depends on how many days left of the basic plan.

Does Magento support this? or anyone got an idea how to achieve it?